# Upload slug file to aws/heroku with nodejs

Tags: amazon-web-services, heroku

I am trying to upload a slug.tgz file to the aws using this tutorial:
[Creating Slugs from Scratch](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-deploying-slugs)
I am using the heroku-client npm module to do the job:

```
const Heroku = require("heroku-client");
const targz  = require("targz");
const request = require('request');
const heroku = new Heroku({ token: "" });
heroku
      .post("/apps", { name: "my-new-app1" })
      .then(app => {
          let name = app.name
          heroku.post("/apps/" + app.name + "/slugs", {
                body: {
                    process_types: {
                        web: "node-v0.10.20-linux-x64/bin/node web.js"
                    }
                }
            })
            .then( async app => {

                let id = app.id;
                await new Promise((x) => {
                    request({
                        url: app.blob.url,
                        method: 'POST',
                        headers: {
                        },
                        body: require("fs").readFileSync(__dirname + "/slug.tgz")
                    }, (error, response, body) => {
                        console.log(body);

                        x()
                    });
                });

                heroku
                  .post("/apps/" + name + "/releases", { slug: id })
                  .then(app => {
                      console.log(app);
                  })
            })
      })
```

every time i try to upload the slug to aws :

```
request({
   url: app.blob.url,
   method: 'POST',
   body: require("fs").readFileSync(__dirname + "/slug.tgz")
   }, (error, response, body) => {
    console.log(body);
    x()
});
```

I am getting this error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message><AWSAccessKeyId>AKIAIO4SD3DCRO7W6IJQ</AWSAccessKeyId><StringToSign>POST
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, i got it working:

```
heroku
      .post("/apps",{name:'example'})
      .then(app => {
          let name = app.name;


          heroku.post("/apps/" + app.name + "/slugs", {
                body: {
                    process_types: {
                        web: "node-v0.10.20-linux-x64/bin/node web.js"
                    }
                }
            })
            .then( async app => {
                let id = app.id;

                await new Promise((x) => {
                    require('fs').readFile(__dirname + "/slug.tgz", function (err, data) {
                        if (err) return console.error(err);
                        request({
                            url  : app.blob.url,
                            body : data,
                            method: "PUT"
                        }, function (err, message,data) {
                            if (err) return console.error(err);

                            console.log(data)
                            x()
                        });
                    })
                });

                heroku
                  .post("/apps/" + name + "/releases", {body:{ "slug": app.id }})
                  .then(app => {

                      console.log(app);

                  }).catch(console.log)
            })
      })
```